# VSTS CI Put Azure App Service offline while deploying

Tags: asp.net, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Currently I am trying to build CI and CD, using VSTS. I have ASP.NET Core 1.1 application that I am trying to deploy in Azure App Service deployment slot.

When I run it first time it's working fine, but second time is throwing exceptions. Here an example with picture bellow, thrown exceptions are for file, which is in use and in that case I should restart my server.

[screenshot of log with publish exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA4es.png)

What I don't want to do is restart server always manually and even I don't want to restart it using PowerShell script.

What I am trying to achieve is, put it offline before deployment starts and then again online when it's completed. I am reading other similar questions, but there is no valid powershell script, which I can break down in 2 steps. I am not sure how should I configure my app service to become offline.

Is it there any VSTS Extension for uploading files and removing them (would work for app_offline.htm) or maybe powershell script which can upload and then remove 
the file?

Other option is to add

```
<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
```

inside my profile, but I am not publishing my project through VS. VSTS CI has been triggered on commit in branch.

How can I proceed with this and what can you advice me?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**
Tried also to add

```
/p:EnableMSDeployAppOffline=true /p:MSDeployUseChecksum=true\
```

inside Build step in CI, as value of property "MSBuild Arguments", but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add build definition step to turn on/off service or powershell script

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Take App Offline` deployment parameter. Described [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/iis-deploy)

Set this option to take the website or app offline by placing an app_offline.htm file in the root directory before the deployment begins. The file will be removed after the synchronization operation completes successfully.

Go to `Additional Deployment Options` of your build step and check that checkbox.

Comment: Do you mean manually upload "app_offline.htm" in root folder of azure app service or source code folder?

Comment: no, read my answer or linked page. there's a property of a build step called `Take App Offline`

Comment: I think I did what you said, enable checkbox and upload app_offline.htm in the root directory and build now is successful. Current problem is that after build app_offline.htm is not automatically removed.
So even after finishing, inside "/site/wwwroot/" I have .htm file

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to supply your own app_offline.htm with this option. This option creates the file and then deletes it after deploy. However since the page is just blank except for the title, it would be nice to be able to use a custom one... but no one seems to know how.